# Hide text only but not whole textview

Tags: android, textview

My goal to hide text  and keep textview occupying its space in the activity , i set already my text to be invisible by using :

```
tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

and when button clicked it show the text , every thing work fine except the result of my code lead to hide whole textview not only the text , because i set my textview background to drawable shape which form red border around the text as:

```
android:background="@drawable/border1" 

  <TextView 
  android:id="@+id/introclusion_tv3" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:background="@drawable/border1" 
  android:textSize="20sp" />
```

when start app you can see empty space only which will be fill with text after button click but there's no border there (which come from shape background) , so it hide whole textview and i need it to hide only text and keep the textview with its background shown when text set to INVISIBLE,

any help will be really appreciated ,thanks.

this is how i did it:

```
  TextView tv11=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.introclusion_tv3);
    tv11.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.introclusion_one)));
    tv11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

then after click the but and write correct password it show the text as:

```
   Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);

        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 dialog.dismiss();

                EditText password = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.password);

                if( password.getText().toString().length() > 0 ) {
                    if( password.getText().toString().equals("test")) {

                        TextView tv11=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.introclusion_tv3);
                        tv11.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
                        tv11.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.introclusion_one)));
                        tv11.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make simple trick : write two string

lets say in your first and second piece of code just remove this line

```
 tv11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

and

```
 tv11.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

so it will be

```
TextView tv11=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.introclusion_tv3);
tv11.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.introclusion_one)));
```

then in second piece write as follow ;

```
  if( password.getText().toString().equals("test")) {

       TextView tv11=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.introclusion_tv3);
       tv11.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));                         
       tv11.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.introclusion_one_appear)));                       
                    }
```

where first string will be empty

```
 <string name="introclusion_one">
```

and second string you will write your text in it

```
 <string name="introclusion_one_appear">
```

Hope help you .

Answer (score 3):

Transparent text color hides the text:

```
<TextView 
  android:id="@+id/introclusion_tv3" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:background="@drawable/border1" 
  android:textColor="@android:color/transparent"
  android:textSize="20sp" />
```

When you want to show your text, change the text color programmatically using method [`setTextColor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor%28int%29):

```
tv11.setTextColor(color);
```

Comment: this is genius.

Answer (score 2):

```
// try this way
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/introclusion_tv3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

save what is in the text view as a string like this:

```
        String x = (String)tv11.getText();
```

then make the text view empty like this:

```
String x = "";
for(int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++){
x +=" ";
}
tv11.setText(x);
```

to make the textview visible again do:

```
tv11.setText(x);
```